# Reverse Route Not Generated

Tags: scala, playframework

I have encountered a situation where the routes are not being generated. In my play service I had situation where all the routes were defined in application routes file as follows:

```
GET /foo packageA.ControllerA.methodA()
… lots of other endpoints under ControllerA

GET /bar packageB.ControllerB.methodB()
… lots of other endpoints under ControllerB

GET /baz packageC.ControllerC.methodC()
… lots of other endpoints under ControllerC
```

When the application is the compiled, the reverse routes are generated.

Because the application routes file was getting too big, it was decided to split out the routes into separate routes file, one for each package like this:

```
routesForA.routes
GET /foo packageA.ControllerA.methodA()
… lots of other endpoints under ControllerA
```

etc

The reverse routes are again generated fine.

However, we wanted to put one endpoint from `packageA.ControllerA` into the routes file for `packageB.ControllerB`.

Say we moved

`packageA.ControllerA.methodA` into the routes file for `packageB.controllerB`.

Then what happened is that the reverse route for `ControllerA.methodA` was generated but all the other reverse routes for `ControllerA` routes (defined in the `packageA` routes file) were not generated.

Is this a bug or feature?

Answer (score 1):

Our main routes file looks a bit different. We delegate in the main routes file to the special ones.

`routes`:

```
->          /foo               foo.Routes
```

So in this example all requests that starts with `/foo` are forwarded to the `foo.routes` file (also in the `conf` folder)

`foo.routes` would look then like

```
GET /methodB     packageB.ControllerB.methodB()
```

So the url for this would be `/foo/methodB`